# Let object state decide form_class in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a manager

```
class OrderManager(models.Manager):
    STATE_REQUESTED = 0
    STATE_PROCESSED = 1
    STATE_CONFIRMED = 2
    STATE_CHOICES = [
        (STATE_REQUESTED, _('Requested')),
        (STATE_PROCESSED, _('Processing')),
        (STATE_CONFIRMED, _('Confirmed')),
    ]

    def requested(self):
        return self.filter(state=self.STATE_REQUESTED)
```

In want different `UpdateView` for each state in which an order can be.

What is the best way to control this? I can make a view for each state, e.g. `RequestOrderView`, `ProcessOrderView`, and `ConfirmOrderView`. But how do I check in the template which view the link should point at?

How do I check if an object is in a specific state both in views and in template? I guess I can populate the template with a queryset with `context['requested_orders'] = Order.objects.requested()` and check in template with

```
{% if object in requested_orders %}
...
<a href="{% url 'process_order' object.id %}">Process order</a>
...
{% elif object in processed_orders %}
...
<a href="{% url 'confirm_order' object.id %}">Confirm order</a>
...
{% endif %}
```

but is it a clever way to do this?

Comment: what about adding a templatename property to your model and using **{% include object.templatename %}** in your template?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you have an url that contains the type directly as a selector?

```
url(
    r'^(?P<action>[-\w]+)_order/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$', 
    views.YourView, 
    name="order")
```

and create your link like this :

```
<a href="{% url 'order' id=object.id action=object.action %}">
    {{ object.action }} order
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the get_form_class() method and return a different form for each of the object states. You can also override the get_template method to return a different template based on the object state.